# Nuxtjs app deployed to Elastic Beanstalk, Javascript not working in the deployed site

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nuxt.js

I tried to deploy my nuxt project on aws elastic beanstalk. I followed this article

https://medium.com/@ajay.dutta94/deploy-vue-nuxt-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-eb-cli-609b1abccb7e

I managed to get it running on aws but for some reason js is not working in the live site

http://edhusk-nuxt-dev.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

> nuxt.config.js

```
  mode: 'universal',
  target: 'server',
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
  },
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  css: [
  ],
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vee-validate'
  ],
  components: true,
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module'
  ],
  modules: [
    ['nuxt-buefy', {
      defaultIconPack: 'fas',
      materialDesignIconsHRef: "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css"
    }],
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1'
  },
  build: {
    transpile: ['vee-validate/dist/rules'],
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

> package.json

```
  "name": "edhusk-nuxt",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "export": "nuxt export",
    "serve": "nuxt serve",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.11.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.13.0",
    "nuxt-buefy": "^0.3.31",
    "vee-validate": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is the information I recieve with command `eb status`

````
Environment details for: edhusk-nuxt-dev
  Application name: edhusk-nuxt
  Region: ap-south-1
  Deployed Version: app-7b0b-200630_211334
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1::platform/Node.js 12 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.1.0
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: edhusk-nuxt-dev.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2020-06-30 15:46:56.092000+00:00
  Status: Ready
  Health: Green```
````